# Cannot get back to my app after posting to facebook/twitter

Tags: facebook, cordova, escaping, return

I have developers working on the backend of my app using phonegap and once the user clicks facebook/twitter share a browser pops up and you can log in and share but after
that you cannot escape back to the app, if you get out of the apps altogether then try and return to my app you're right back at the facebook/twitter screen instead of in my app.  This is only happening on iphon because on android they have a back button.  The only way to get back into the app is to restart the iphone/ipod to get back to open
the app from beginning.  I cannot have this as the only option for
people to share from my app as it would be horrible and could ruin my
app before I launch it.  They say their is no way to fix it but Im sure its fixable so I am trying to get any info on this that I can.

The other issue is the facebook post itself. currently it post like this

Sent from Appname(with link to app)
www.appname
Text here

but this is kinda counter intuitive because the actual message should
be on top otherwise it will get lost in the other text.  They said
this is the only way facebook allows it.  Is it possible to get it like this

Text here
Sent from appname(linke here)
www.appname.com

Again any help on these two issues would be great so I can pass the
info to my developers.

Comment: If your "developers" are telling you that something thousands of apps do all the time is not possible, I think it's time to start questioning their competence.